# Avoiding POST requests resulting in "400 - Bad Request" status code in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application using annotation configuration. My test controller looks like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNumber(@RequestParam("name") Long someNumber) {
    ...
    return "redirect:/showAll/";
}
```

When a user posts data to this controller and does not enter a valid Long number ("someNumber"), Spring MVC responds with a 400 - Bad Request HTTP status code. My application does not get a chance to react on that error.

How is this problem usually handled?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to handle this is to add a 'required' parameter into RequestParam annotation.

```
@RequestParam(value="name", required=false)
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

Comment: The more interesting thing about it is that if I do not enter enything for the parameter "name" I get "HTTP Status 400 - Required Long parameter 'name' is not present" although it is defined being not required by the following method signature: public String addNumber(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) Long name)

Comment: Just tested this solution with signature addNumber(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false) . URLs /simple/list and /simple/list?name= set name to null, /simple/list?name=123 set name to 123. Will try with POST.

Comment: Works for me with POST method and redirect. Tested with no parameter, name= and name=123.

Comment: It's a regression in version 3.2.3. I tested with 3.2.2.https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10592

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to declare a default value for your parameter and then check that in application code:

```
@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="-1")
```

Or, if no default makes sense, just go with @diafour's answer and you'll get a `null` value.